# CRM 2011 call to mscrmsevices prompting for credentials

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-4, dynamics-crm-2011

I am reconfiguring an application that we had running in CRM 4.0 to run in CRM 2011. It was previously called from a toolbar button using javascript.

I have transferred the javascript to a web resource and reconfigured the ribbon to hold the button and call the required function within the library.

When testing this however, I am being prompted for username and password which when entered 3 or so times returns the error "'null' is null or not an object".

I am not sure why I am getting prompted for credentials when this did not happen in CRM 4.0.

Any ideas what may be causing this?

The javascript is below:

```
try 
{
var ADD_LETTER='1';
var SAVE_DOC_IN_CRM='1';
var STORE_TO_PRINT='1';
var SEND_EMAIL='1';
var SHOW_PARAGRAPHS='1';
var xml = '' +'&lt;?xml version=\'1.0\' encoding=\'utf-8\'?&gt;' +'&lt;soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\' xmlns:xsi=\'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\' xmlns:xsd=\'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\'&gt;'+GenerateAuthenticationHeader() +' &lt;soap:Body&gt;' +' &lt;RetrieveMultiple xmlns=\'http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2007/WebServices\'&gt;' +' &lt;query xmlns:q1=\'http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2006/Query\' xsi:type=\'q1:QueryExpression\'&gt;' +' &lt;q1:EntityName&gt;systemuser&lt;/q1:EntityName&gt;' +' &lt;q1:ColumnSet xsi:type=\'q1:ColumnSet\'&gt;' +' &lt;q1:Attributes&gt;' +' &lt;q1:Attribute&gt;systemuserid&lt;/q1:Attribute&gt;' +' &lt;/q1:Attributes&gt;' +' &lt;/q1:ColumnSet&gt;' +' &lt;q1:Distinct&gt;false&lt;/q1:Distinct&gt;' +' &lt;q1:Criteria&gt;' +' &lt;q1:FilterOperator&gt;And&lt;/q1:FilterOperator&gt;' +' &lt;q1:Conditions&gt;' +' &lt;q1:Condition&gt;' +' &lt;q1:AttributeName&gt;systemuserid&lt;/q1:AttributeName&gt;' +' &lt;q1:Operator&gt;EqualUserId&lt;/q1:Operator&gt;' +' &lt;/q1:Condition&gt;' +' &lt;/q1:Conditions&gt;' +' &lt;/q1:Criteria&gt;' +' &lt;/query&gt;' +' &lt;/RetrieveMultiple&gt;' +' &lt;/soap:Body&gt;' +'&lt;/soap:Envelope&gt;' +'';
var xmlHttpRequest = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');
xmlHttpRequest.Open('POST', '/mscrmservices/2007/CrmService.asmx', false);
xmlHttpRequest.setRequestHeader('SOAPAction', 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2007/WebServices/RetrieveMultiple');
xmlHttpRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml; charset=utf-8');
xmlHttpRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-Length', xml.length);
xmlHttpRequest.send(xml);
var resultXml = xmlHttpRequest.responseXML;
var entityNode = resultXml.selectSingleNode('//RetrieveMultipleResult/BusinessEntities/BusinessEntity');
var useridNode = entityNode.selectSingleNode('q1:systemuserid');
var sUserId = (useridNode == null) ? '' : useridNode.text;
var sGUID = crmForm.ObjectId;
var sEntity = crmForm.ObjectTypeName;
var sURL = '/ISV/Mergedabc/Mergedabc.aspx?org=' + ORG_UNIQUE_NAME + '&amp;guid=' + sGUID + '&amp;ety=' + sEntity + '&amp;userid=' + sUserId + '&amp;indid=' + sGUID + '&amp;indtype=' + crmForm.ObjectTypeCode + '&amp;indtypename=' + sEntity + '&amp;addletter=' + ADD_LETTER + '&amp;docincrm=' + SAVE_DOC_IN_CRM + '&amp;storetoprint=' + STORE_TO_PRINT + '&amp;emaildoc=' + SEND_EMAIL + '&amp;showparas=' + SHOW_PARAGRAPHS;
var objRet = window.showModalDialog(prependOrgName(sURL));

if(objRet != null)
{
if (objRet.length > 0) 
{
    var o = objRet[0];
    if (o.ret == true) 
    {
        alert('Merge Completed.');
    }
    else {
        alert('Unable to merge document.');
    }
}
else 
{
    alert('No merge information returned.');
}
}
}
catch (e) 
{
alert(e.message);
}
```

It looks as though this is happening when it tries to call the CrmService and is causing a 401 error.

Any suggestions on how to fix this will be appreciated,

Thanks!!

Comment: Does the login request come up before the page pops up or after (maybe when you click Save on the pop-up)?  In other words, are you sure the login request is coming from this javascript or could it be coming from an action on the ASPX page that pops up?

Comment: Before. I don't even get as far as the aspx page. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed – the issue was the XML-isation of all the `%amp;` `%lt;` `%gt;` instead of `%`, `<` and `>` in the SOAP call.